# Schema GeneralContractor mainEntityOfPage: WebSite ~OR~ WebSite about: GeneralContractor ??

Tags: schema

GeneralContractor mainEntityOfPage: WebSite ~OR~ WebSite about: GeneralContractor

For most effective discovery of my company, it's website, and most importantly for eventually evolving towards the point where a successful enough web search might someday offer up individual product snippets referencing availability for each of our company's website's individual service offerings' webpages, should I begin building my Schema as

GeneralContractor mainEntityOfPage: WebSite
    makesOffer: Offer

or as

WebSite about: GeneralContractor (or maybe as WebSite mainEntity: GeneralContractor )
    Offers: Offer

or perhaps yet some other structure I've yet to discover?

Trimmed down examples of first of these two alternatives are shown below.

Additional related questions include:

1) is it preferable to use of the "Place or PostalAddress" as shown below, or by means of the GeneralContractor itemprop="location", or possibly via both?

2) should BOTH the now depreciated "map" and replacement "hasMap" be used for backward compatibility with additional search engines?

3) is there a means of, and benefit to, using the geo:GeoShape to define a service territory indication?

4) is usage of alternative itemprop="availability" contents like "24/7 Rapid Response" rather than "InStock" acceptable, or not?  The thought of a truncated "Fire Damage" being shown as "InStock" to a Fire victim just makes me shudder...

5) is there a potential value to investigating enumerating some sort of Thing:potentialAction Action:object Thing... that might eventually SOMEHOW manage to communicate into the Knowledge graph something like Restorer:restores Fire:Burned Damaged:Buildings SERVICE:WebPage ?

## Schema as: GeneralContractor mainEntityOfPage: WebSite

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeneralContractor">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Pearl Bay Rainbow" />
    <meta itemprop="logo" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/Pearl_Bay_Rainbow_Logo.png" />
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="912 De La Vina Street" />
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Santa Barbara" />
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="California" />
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US" />
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="93101" />
    </div>
        <!-- Map URLs shortened to fit Code Snippet Window -->
        <meta itemprop="hasMap" content="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pearl+Bay+Rainbow" />
        <meta itemprop="map" content="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pearl+Bay+Rainbow" />
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com"/>
    <div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" />
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Pearl Bay Rainbow" />
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com" />
        <meta itemprop="keywords" content="Pearl Bay,Santa Barbara,Building Damage Restoration,..." />
        <meta itemprop="copyrightHolder" content="Pearl Bay Corporation" />
        <meta itemprop="copyrightYear" content="2015" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="24/7 Fire Damage Restoration" />
        <meta itemprop="alternateName" content="Fire Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="General Contractor / Restoration / Building Damage / Fire Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Fire Damage Repair &amp; Smoke Odor Removal." />
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/firedamage.html" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="24/7 Rapid Response" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="24/7 Water Damage Restoration" />
        <meta itemprop="alternateName" content="Water Damage Cleanup" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="General Contractor / Restoration / Building Damage / Water Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Get You Clean &amp; Dry, Restored &amp; Rebuilt." />
        <meta itemtype="offer" itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/waterdamage.html" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="24/7 Rapid Response" />
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

## Schema as: WebSite about: GeneralContractor ( or  WebSite mainEntity: GeneralContractor )

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Pearl Bay Rainbow" />
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com" />
    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="Pearl Bay,Santa Barbara,Building Damage Restoration,..." />
    <meta itemprop="copyrightHolder" content="Pearl Bay Corporation" />
    <meta itemprop="copyrightYear" content="2015" />

    <div itemprop="about" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeneralContractor">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Pearl Bay Rainbow" />
        <meta itemprop="logo" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/Pearl_Bay_Rainbow_Logo.png" />
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="912 De La Vina Street" />
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Santa Barbara" />
            <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="California" />
            <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US" />
            <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="93101" />
        </div>
        <!-- Map URLs shortened to fit Code Snippet Window -->
        <meta itemprop="map" content="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pearl+Bay+Rainbow" />
        <meta itemprop="hasMap" content="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pearl+Bay+Rainbow" />
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com"/>


    <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="24/7 Fire Damage Restoration" />
        <meta itemprop="alternateName" content="Fire Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="General Contractor / Restoration / Building Damage / Fire Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Fire Damage Repair &amp; Smoke Odor Removal." />
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/firedamage.html" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="24/7 Rapid Response" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="24/7 Water Damage Restoration" />
        <meta itemprop="alternateName" content="Water Damage Cleanup" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="General Contractor / Restoration / Building Damage / Water Damage Restored" />
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Get You Clean &amp; Dry, Restored &amp; Rebuilt." />
        <meta itemtype="offer" itemprop="url" content="http://PearlBayCorp.com/waterdamage.html" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="24/7 Rapid Response" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something similar to the latter version of your second example.

### mainEntityOfPage vs url

As for `mainEntityOfPage`, this is a property used to show that some item on the page is actually the `mainEntity` of another page, and is therefore a sort of more specific alternative to `url`.  For example, if you have a list of products on a category page, you may want to mark up their anchors/hrefs/urls as `mainEntityOfPage` rather than `url`, seeing as how each product in the list is actually the main entity being described by their individual pages.

In your case, it seems like the whole site is dedicated to the `GeneralContractor` in question, and so the `mainEntityOfPage` is not necessary at all.  However, if you have someone write up a blog post and mention your business/site, I'd recommend them to mark up the link with schema, to indicate that the `mainEntityOfPage` to which the link is pointing to is the `GeneralContractor`.

### mainEntity vs about

So, on your homepage, I think `WebSite > mainEntity/GeneralContractor` is best.

While *if you had a seperate "about me/us" page*, I'd recommend `WebSite > AboutPage > about/GeneralContractor`

---

From the [schema.org blog article on mainEntityOfPage](https://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html#mainEntityBackground):

> mainEntity(OfPage)
>
> Background information on mainEntityOfPage / mainEntity properties.
>
> mainEntityOfPage "Indicates a page (or other CreativeWork) for which this thing is the main entity being described."
>
> Many (but not all) pages have a fairly clear primary topic, some entity or thing that the page describes. For example a restaurant's home page might be primarily about that Restaurant, or an event listing page might represent a single event. **The mainEntity and mainEntityOfPage properties allow you to explicitly express the relationship between the page and the primary entity.**
>
> Related properties include sameAs, about, and url.
>
> The sameAs and url properties are both similar to mainEntityOfPage. The url property should be reserved to refer to more official or authoritative web pages, such as the item’s official website. The sameAs property also relates a thing to a page that indirectly identifies it. Whereas sameAs emphasises well known pages, **the mainEntityOfPage property serves more to clarify which of several entities is the main one for that page.**
>
> **mainEntityOfPage can be used for any page, including those not recognized as authoritative for that entity.** For example, for a product, sameAs might refer to a page on the manufacturer’s official site with specs for the product, while mainEntityOfPage might be used on pages within various retailers’ sites giving details for the same product.
>
> **about is similar to mainEntity, with two key differences.** First, about can refer to multiple entities/topics, while mainEntity should be used for only the primary one. Second, some pages have a primary entity that itself describes some other entity. For example, one web page may display a news article about a particular person. Another page may display a product review for a particular product. In these cases, mainEntity for the pages should refer to the news article or review, respectively, while about would more properly refer to the person or product.

---

As for your other questions, 1-5, I'd kindly recommend that you start a separate StackOverflow question thread, as each of those questions can easily turn into a separate and deep topic to explore.

Let me know if you have any questions related to this specific issue.